# sort a json file with 2 entries

Tags: json, sorting

I have a json file like

```
 var data = {
     "list":[

{
    "g": "zas",
    "e": "wef"
},
{
    "g": "abc",
    "e": "ew"
},
{
    "g": "wee",
    "e": "asd"
},.....
```

How do I sort the entries w.r.t "g"
so that I get abc then wee and then zas....
I want the sort changes permanently in the json file

Comment: [That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript object literal.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use a custom comparator function to sort an array like so:

```
data.list.sort(function (a, b)
{
    return a.g > b.g ? 1 : a.g < b.g ? -1 : 0
});
```

[`Array.sort` @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Reading and writing the file is on you, though, since you haven't provided much context for the question, and figuring out file IO is an exercise in RTFM.