# Sort Java Script Object literals

Tags: java, json, sorting

I inherited a project that uses JSON to perform a series of operations as denoted by each object literal.  I have zero experience with JSON and while the notation is straight forward, I'm finding working with the object literals less so.

Consider the following file:

```
[{
    "Name": "Hingle McCringleberry",
    "ID": "4"
},
{
    "Name": "Scoish Velociraptor Maloish",
    "ID": "1"
},
{
    "Name": "DGlester Hardunkichud",
    "ID": "3"
}]
```

Using Java, I want to sort them by ID.  I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238830/sort-a-json-file-with-2-entries) that talks about implementing a JavaScript sort method, but I'm unsure how to do this in practice.  I'm using a [JsonFactory](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory.html) and [JsonParser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.html) to read and iterate over the file, but I need them to be sorted before I can process them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Jackson to parse these, I assume you must be parsing them into a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some sort of object with an ID and name.  If that is the case, simply write a standard [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  For example:

**NamedObject.java:**

```
public class NamedObject {
    // I'm using public fields instead of getters/setters for brevity,
    // since this is just sample code.

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public int id;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;
}
```

**NamedObjectIdComparator.java:**

```
public class NamedObjectIdComparator implements Comparator<NamedObject> {
    public int compare(NamedObject object1, NamedObject object2) {
        return object1.id - object2.id;
    }
}
```

Then, to sort the list of objects:

```
List<NamedObject> objects = // parse using JsonParser
Collections.sort(objects, new NamedObjectIdComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jackson library, but I am sure jackson can convert JSON to Java `List` object (some methods call `readValueXXX` I guess).

Once we got a Java `List`, **[Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)** can do the sorting.